# Best way to fold a shirt for a lazy bachelor

Tags: clothing, time, laundry

Like most lazy men I hate folding laundry, and when I do it tends to be messy. Sometimes everything is wrinkled by the time I get to it. Most of my laundry is t-shirts, so what is the best way I can fold a t-shirt without much effort?

Comment: Good question, folding is tedious!

Answer (score 11):

I hang all my t-shirts on hangers in a closet. They are never wrinkled (provided I pull them out of the dryer soon after it turns off).

Comment: At first I was going to say that is a lot of work but it is probably a lot faster then folding.

Comment: @ChristianJuth Faster and (I think) more foolproof! It's tough to add a wrinkle to a shirt on a hanger, but easy to add one to a folded shirt sitting in a drawer.

Comment: And by hanging your shirts, you can better find which one you are looking for! I have a lot of the same color shirts and I could never figure out which was which if they were folded

Comment: I don't use a dryer, I put them on hangers and hang them up to dry like that. If they are looking a bit wrinkly I just run my hand over the wrinkles. Works for T-shirts as well.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few methods out there that claim to be "3 seconds" but this is my favorite. It takes a little practice but it will speed up your folding time up by a lot and your clothes will look neater.

Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAxhr0j0thY

Step by step:

[image: fold shirt step by step]

I also add this extra step. It helps hold the shirts together and keep your drawers neat. Just add one extra fold and place your shirts like files in your dresser drawer.

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with this method: this style of folding comes apart easily, compared to the traditional style. Make sure you keep that into account.

Comment: @Quincunx Yeah, once you fold the shirt, you can't easily move it without everything falling out from underneath. Looks good on video, but I never  found this technique particularly useful.

Comment: Personally, I add an extra fold so they fit in the drawer upright. I find this fixes the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxLiFBxVOxA