# Is there a neater way to fold a shirt?

Tags: clothing

It's so difficult to fold a shirt. Every time I try it comes out unevenly folded. Is there a better/neater way to do this? I would love to fold a shirt the way clothing stores fold their shirts; as you see them on display.

Comment: I'm leaving this question open, and closing http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6585/best-way-to-fold-a-shirt-for-a-lazy-bachelor as a duplicate, even though it's older. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/188558) for more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you search for [how to fold a shirt in under 2 seconds](//google.com/search?q=how+to+fold+a+shirt+in+under+2+seconds) you'll find lots of videos and references on how to fold a shirt quickly without the need of anything but a shirt and a table (or flat surface).

One of the top references is the [video](//youtu.be/uz6rjbw0ZA0) from  [DaveHax.com](//davehax.com/), which has spun off into multiple other sites. The image below is constructed from pictures from the video, and I found the compilation at http://www.howtoinstructions.org/how-to-fold-a-shirt-in-under-2-seconds/:

[image: Picture from davehax.com video on folding shirts]

My written instructions to accompany this picture are as follows:

1. After putting the shirt on a table, imagine a line at the middle
2. Then imagine another line from top to bottom at an quarter from the left
3. Name the points from top to bottom as **B** at the shoulder, **A** at the crossing section, and **C** at the bottom of shirt
4. Pinch at **A** with your left hand, and pick up **B** with your right hand
5. Move right hand over and pick up **C**
6. Lift both hands in a swift motion, and move it a little away from you
7. Put it down on the table again, with a little drag towards yourself, before folding it back completing the fold
8. Watch your nicely folded shirt, before putting it away

The instructions are somewhat lengthy, but once you get the hang of it, you'll do it almost without thinking. I've been using this technique for some years now, and found it to be very efficient.

An extension to this folding technique it lift by the upper part, and fold it yet another time. This allows for an even smaller package, and can be used if you want to stack the shirts in a drawer, where each shirt can be readily accessible. To fold it this extra times, does also make the folded shirt slight more stable.

Finally, this technique can also be used on long sleeved shirts, with the addition of folding the long sleeves an extra time on top of the rest of the shirt.

Answer (score 13):

I use something like this:

[image: Shirt folder]

You lay the shirt on it, fold in the sides, then the bottom, and you have a nice, flat, pretty perfectly folded shirt. Once you get the hang of it, you can fold a lot of shirts pretty quickly.

Comment: Where can I get order one of those from?

Comment: @Ginger I think I got mine at a dollar store. Walmart or similar stores may have them as well.

Comment: This look like something that could be made from cardboard and duck tape!  I like it!

Comment: @Minnow the duct tape alone will be more expensive. :) when buying one, make sure it fits your size, the one I got did not work with XXL. :P that's how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Twh-oF6VHUo

Comment: @Minnow I actually just saw a comparison of this and holroy's answer on truTV's *Hack my Life* (can't find the video online) and that guy did made his FlipFold with cardboard and duct tape.
The key message was: Both techniques are equally fast, but with the (DYI) FlipFold you'll get nicer results.

Comment: I had heard about this method but had forgotten since then. Folding shirts is so tedious to me (folding has to be *perfect*... unreachable wish) and damn time-consuming... I just hate this chore. Then I landed on this page. I'm feeling so relieved right now. Thank you.